# Protractor - check element is empty

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I want to check the span inside each li has some text.

```
 <ul class="items">
   <li><span>First</span></li>
   <li><span>Second</span></li>
   <li><span>Third</span></li>
</ul>
```

I tried:

```
 element.all(by.css('.items li')).each(function(elem, index) {
    elem(by.tagName('span')).getAttribute('value').then(function(text) {
        expect(text).toBeNonEmptyString();
    });
```

Comment: Try `expect(text.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 element.all(by.css('.items li')).each(function(elem) {
      elem(by.tagName('span')).getText().then(function(text) {
         expect(text).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the text inside is not an empty string.

```
element.all(by.css('.items li')).each(function(elem) {
      elem(by.tagName('span')).getText().then(function(text) {
         expect(text).not.toEqual("");
});
```